# Attempting to use scm:tag in a Jenkins job for a Git repository that requires a username/password

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I am attempting to configure a Jenkins/Maven/Git release build job as described by Axel Fontaine (http://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html). I made the additions to my POM as he described, and configured my Jenkins job accordingly.

In the Source Code Management section I entered the Repository URL for our internally hosted instance of Stash (which requires a username and password - SSH keys are not an option): `https://stash.mycompany.com/scm/st_proj/my_repo.git`

I provided the username/password credentials.

As in the blog post I created a Maven pre-step that has the goals `versions:set -DnewVersion=$BUILD_NUMBER`.

And also as in the blog post I set the goals for the build to `deploy scm:tag`.

When the job executes I get the following error.

```
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR]
(gnome-ssh-askpass:32706):  Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
error: unable to read askpass response from '/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://stash.mycompany.com': No such device or address
```

I realize this is because the Git command is attempting to prompt me for a username and password, but since this is run as a Jenkins' job there is no display for it to send the prompt to.

**Why am I being prompted for a username and password when I have them set earlier in the job configuration?** I know they are correct because they were required to clone the repository.

Comment: Have you correctly setup your servers in your settings.xml file? locally as well as on your CI system?

Comment: I thought so, @khmarbaise. What server settings should I be focused on for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the things manually on your jenkins server ? The hint about `https://stash.mycompany.com': No such device or address` looks like network problems.

Comment: @khmarbaise, If I run `git push` from the command line as the Jenkins user I get prompted for a username and password. Typing those in, and I get the message `no changes added to commit`. So I don't think the issue is a networking one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another (and much better) solution:

In Jenkins instead of using the scm:tag goal, use the Git Publisher post-build action. Here you can set and push a tag to the repository and the plugin uses the credentials stored in Jenkins!

[image: Screen capture of Git Publisher section]

Comment: I know this post is an year old. But do you know if we can create a new tag with the version defined in the pom.xml? will something like v-${project.version} [which will resolve to something like v-2.0.0]? I'm not sure if the ${project.version} would be resolved here?

Comment: @user320550 I don't know of a way to do that off hand, but you can go the other way. If you use the EnvInject plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) you could read a properties file that contains your version number from the checked out directory. That version would be available for your use in a tag. You can then use the Maven versions plugin to set the version in the POM at build time. That way your version numbers are all set from the same source.

Answer (score 3):

After pounding on this for a while I've found a workaround - if not a solution. (Solutions are still welcome)

1. Log into the Jenkins build slave (as the user that runs the build jobs)
2. Set the credential cache `git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 600'`

Now when the credentials are used to clone the repository they are cached by Git for the subsequent push command.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. The Git Publisher post-build action was not an option, as I wanted to specify the git commit id to be tagged (not rely on HEAD being the commit to tag).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Git Publisher tags the version that was checked out for the build.

Comment: We've had a similar issue, credential helper was using default timeout of 900 seconds, so when the build took (sporadically) longer than 15 minutes, it was not unable to push :) Thanks for pointing us to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your git credentials in maven too.

First declare a server in maven *settings.xml* under `<settings> <servers>`

```
<server>
    <id>gitserver</id>
    <username>git-user</username>
    <password>**************</password>
</server>
```

then reference your server in your project *pom.xml* properties

```
<project.scm.id>gitserver</project.scm.id>
```

See http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/faq.html#credentials